# Implement Worker Role in Windows Azure

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-worker-roles

We want to receive signals in Windows Azure Cloud Service and would like some feedback on our strategy.

---

Our current Project:

- **Physical GPS unit** that runs as a client.
- **Windows Azure Cloud Service** that runs as a server.

1) Physical GPS unit: We are using XT-4000[Xirgo Technologies] physical Gps unit which is a powerful tracking, monitoring and control gateway device. This device requires UDP or TCP port to communicate.

2) Windows Azure Cloud Service: Here we need to open up a TCP listener, which will listen for incoming data which is pushed by the device [XT-4000].

Here's what we are thinking our strategy should be. All advice is appreciated.

- Using Worker Role.
- Set the TCP listener for receiving incoming signals from device.

**[But the question is what should be the IPaddress and port no. of Windows Azure Cloud Service as the device needs to send the data with the help of IPaddress and port no.]**

*The following command will be SET in the device to push data*

**Command for the device**

```
   “+XT:1001,<Port no>,<IPaddress>,<1>”
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can have any port number that you want (UDP or TCP).  Just set it in the config file for the service.

2) The IP address will be a little tricky.  Once you deploy your service you will be assigned a VIP.  This will not change *SO LONG AS* you do not delete the service.  If you do, you will lose the VIP & the devices will stop working.  It would be better if the device could accept a URL, which would eliminate the problem entirely.  Regardless, once deployed you can still update the service, but you will need to use upgrade vs delete/redeploy or VIP swap.

Pat